# Finding and updating performance on deeply nested Arrays in Objects with findIndex

Tags: javascript

I have the following data structure:

```
const myData = [
        {
            "trips": [
                {
                    "destination": "Hungary",
                    "id": "34547",
                    "stars": 0
                },
                {
                    "destination": "Hungary",
                    "id": "14542",
                    "stars": 0
                },
                {
                    "destination": "Hungary",
                    "id": "88247",
                    "stars": 0
                },
                {
                    "destination": "Hungary",
                    "id": "11447",
                    "stars": 0
                },
            ],
            "descr": "Holidays",
            "id": "243567"
        },
    ]
```

Assuming we have N objects with unique IDs:

Given the item `id`, the trip `id`, and a replacement trip object, find and replace the trip object.

Example:

```
const itemId = 243567;
const tripId = 14542;

const replacement = { 
  destination: Beijing
  id: 14542
  stars: 4
};;
```

My solution was the following:

```js
const myData = [{
  "trips": [{
      "destination": "Hungary",
      "id": "34547",
      "stars": 0
    },
    {
      "destination": "Hungary",
      "id": "14542",
      "stars": 0
    },
    {
      "destination": "Hungary",
      "id": "88247",
      "stars": 0
    },
    {
      "destination": "Hungary",
      "id": "11447",
      "stars": 0
    },
  ],
  "descr": "Holidays",
  "id": "243567"
}];

const itemId = 243567;
const tripId = 14542;

const replacement = {
  destination: "Beijing"
  id: 14542
  stars: 4
};

const itemIndex = myData
  .findIndex(element => element.id === itemId);
const tripIndex = myData[itemIndex].trips
  .findIndex(element => element.id === tripId);
Object.assign(myData[itemIndex].trips[tripIndex], replacement);
```

How would this solution perform and are there faster ways to implement it?

Comment: If you need to do this multiple times, you could convert the structure into nested objects with `itemId` and `tripId` as keys, so your lookup would be something like `myData[itemId][tripId]`.

Comment: Not much control over the structure :(

Comment: Not even a possibility to create a lookup table with indices? e.g., `index[itemId][tripId] // => [12, 3]`

Comment: its an API response

Comment: Will you be making repeat updates to the `myData` object  or is it for single use?

Comment: There will be frequent updates yes.

Comment: And for each update, you have to pull the data structure from the API again? Or you just do it once?

Comment: Then you can locally (once you get the API response) create the lookup so you can act faster from that point on.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: So you pull the big chunk of data once. And then you update-update-update? Or, any time you have to update, you have to fetch the big chunk of data again?

Comment: The API response is not cached so we'll probably need to refetch it at every page load in order to have the latest data available.

Comment: Then that lookup won't offer any help if after each update you re-fetch the data.

Comment: So ok, let me rephrase. (1) page opens, (2) you fetch the big chunk of data, (3) you fetch multiple smaller chunks with which you update the big chunk. Is that how it works?

Comment: I actually simplified the problem to make it easier to describe - its a bit more tricky. Chat?

Comment: Sure. Chat sounds good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to perform *one* such look-up and mutation for a given data set, then what you currently do is fine.

If however, you will perform multiple look-ups and mutations within the same data set (so before it gets reloaded), then you should key the data by id and trip id. For that you could use this function, which you should call once after the data set is loaded:

```js
function hashData(myData) {
    const result = {};    
    for (const row of myData) {
        const obj = result[row.id] = {};
        for (const trip of row.trips) {
            obj[trip.id] = trip;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// Sample data
const myData = [{ "trips": [{"destination": "Hungary", "id": "34547", "stars": 0 },{"destination": "Hungary", "id": "14542", "stars": 0 },{"destination": "Hungary", "id": "88247", "stars": 0 },{"destination": "Hungary", "id": "11447", "stars": 0}], "descr": "Holidays", "id": "243567"}];

// Key it by id and trip id:
const hash = hashData(myData);

// Mutate one particular entry:
Object.assign(hash[243567][88247], { destination: 'PARADISE', id: "9999", stars: 5 });

// Display result
console.log(myData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If you don't mind more verbose code, then replacing `Object.assign` with individual assignments will give better performance in current browsers:

```
const obj = hash[243567][88247];
obj.destination = 'PARADISE';
obj.id = "9999";
obj.stars = 5;
```

Comment: You can actually take advantage of references and just go ahead and replace the referenced object. No `Object.assign` needed

Comment: @eltonkamami, not sure what you mean, but `hash[243567][88247] = { .... }` would *replace* the reference in the hash, and thereby disconnect it from the object in the original data.

Comment: `hash[243567][88247].name = 'new name'` , `hash[243567][88247].destination = ....`

Comment: Sure, that works, but then you are doing exactly the same as what `Object.assign` is doing but with repeated look-ups in `hash`.

Comment: `Object.assign` will create a new object and copy the values of the source objects to the first one. Not measured but pretty sure its more expensive

Comment: That might be implementation specific. It will be a trade-off between the object creation and the repeated index lookup in `hash`.

Comment: @eltonkamami, I added your suggestion to my answer with first an assignment to a variable so that lookup does not have to be repeated. This will indeed outperform `Object.assign`.

Comment: Is `Object.assign` slow because it hasn't yet been optimized in current browsers?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos, that is what I think. In my opinion, JS engines could optimise `Object.assign` calls when the second (third, fourth,...) arguments are object literals. In that case it is not really necessary for those objects to be actually created as they have no other use than to provide key/value pairs. Maybe such optimisation is already happening in some engines -- I did not look further into this.